# There's an image named g.gif somewhere in my WordPress site

Tags: theme-development, css, front-end

I am looking for this pixel which appears full width in my mobile site, so I want to remove it.

[image]

Image URL: `http://pixel.wp.com/g.gif?v=ext&j=1%3A3.5.3&blog=66797659&post=0&tz=-4&srv=synstudioblog.staging.wpengine.com&host=synstudioblog.staging.wpengine.com&ref=&rand=0.8039163304492831`

Well, I can see it's g.gif and assume it has something to do with Wordpress keeping track of the blog, but I want to grab it and edit its CSS style. The thing is it doesn't show up in the page source or when I search my theme source code.

What is this `g.gif` in Wordpress about? Any info about this would be very helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the Jetpack Stats image, it's necessary to track the stats. You can disable it by disabling Jetpack Stats but it shouldn't be full width, that will be a CSS problem

Comment: Got it...thanks. Well, I must have set default width to 100% that's why this is happening.